# Does going from SPL with TMG to PPL(A) automatically give me a PPL(A) TMG rating?

Tags: easa-regulations, ppl, easa, tmg

I am currently training for PPL(A) while holding an SPL with TMG rating.

Since I have more than 24 hours on TMG, I only need 15 hours of flying to obtain the PPL(A) license according to the EASA Part FCL.

My question is: Will I automatically receive the TMG rating with my PPL(A) after my skilltest, or will my TMG rating only be associated with my SPL?

In my opinion, I would find it strange, if I was not allowed to use my TMG rating on my PPL(A), since I was taught to fly powered aircraft on a TMG.

Comment: In FAA land (so not an answer, but may be similar), you can only hold one level of pilot certificate at a time. In the above case, your SPL would be replaced by a PPL with ratings for both ASEL and GLI, but the GLI rating would be restricted to SPL privileges since you haven't passed the PPL test in a glider yet.